# How to use third party binaries in IBM cloud functions

Tags: binary, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I want to use the binaries bwa and samtools in IBM cloud functions.
I've tried to include both in the .zip as explained [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-prep#prep_python_local_virtenv) but both executables are missing some shared libraries.
What would be a general approach to fix those sorts of problems?
Do I have to create a docker image for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build and use your Docker image. That is recommended for more complex dependencies. The .zip could work, but it requires some laser focus in catching all dependencies.